# Notation for meta-variable or placeholder variable

Tags: notation

I have an ODE model for a biological system which has state variables named $A, B, C, \dots$, and the expressions for their derivatives contain the unknown functions $f_A, f_B, f_C, \dots$.

I was typing up a description for each but it ended being very repetitive:

$$\begin{matrix}
f_A :& (\text{function related to variable } A )\\
f_B :& (\text{function related to variable } B )\\
f_C :& (\text{function related to variable } C )\\
\vdots & \vdots
\end{matrix}$$

If I had labeled my variables $x_1, x_2, x_3, \dots$ it would be a lot more clear to write

$$
f_i : \; ( \text{function related to variable } x_i ),
\quad i = 1 \dots n
$$

In this case $i$ is the common notation for an integer index. Is there an equivalent standard notation when the value of the variable is a symbol, or another variable? I've been using the $*$ symbol:

$$
f_* : \quad ( \text{function related to variable } * ),
\quad * \in \{A, B, C, \dots\}
$$

but it seems confusing. The important thing is that the domain of $*$ is the set of *variables* $\{A, B, C, \dots\}$, not the set of *values* of those variables (which are real numbers). This is why I refer to it as a meta-variable in the title, although I'm not sure that is the correct term.

I've seen $\square$ used a as a placeholder for a binary operator, like $x \square y$, don't know if that applies here. All information I've been able to find is specifically for mathematical logic.

Answer (score 1):

What you seem to be describing is an indexed family of functions, where the indexing set is something other than the natural numbers.  In my own work, I have used the notation
$$ \{ f_{\imath} \}_{\imath \in \mathscr{I} }. $$
Here, $\imath$ (typset as `\imath`) is an index and $\mathscr{I}$ (typeset as `\mathscr{I}`) is an index set, which could be anything (the natural numbers, the real numbers, the $p$-adic numbers, a collection of variables (whatever that means), the ingredients in my pancake recipe... whatevs).  Folland uses a similar notation in [his text on real analysis](https://books.google.com/books/about/Real_Analysis.html?id=wI4fAwAAQBAJ).  Specifically, in his section on topology, he uses
$$ \langle f_{\lambda} \rangle $$
to denote a net (a kind of generalized sequence), where the index $\lambda$ is contained in some index set $\Lambda$.

The overall point here is that the specific symbols here aren't really that important—the important idea is to recognize that *any* set can serve as an index set.  As long as you clearly indicate what your index set is, there is likely to be no confusion.

That being said, I would probably *avoid* something like $f_\ast$.  The $\ast$ looks like an unspecified index to me, which implies that you could plug in just about any ol' thing.  It lacks specificity (though that is a purely opinionated aesthetic judgement).  It is also possible, depending on context, that this could be confused with other uses of $(\cdot)_{\ast}$ or $(\cdot)^\ast$, such as (co)homology groups or the adjoint operator.

Finally (and, again, this is an opinion), taking your index set to be $\mathscr{I}$ or $\Lambda$ makes it easier to write down *distinct* elements.  For example, $\iota$ and $\jmath$ (or even $i$ and $j$) "look like" elements of an index set $\mathscr{I}$, while $\lambda$, $\mu$, $\nu$ (and so on) "look like" elements of an index set $\Lambda$.  To what set does $\ast$ belong, and what are the other elements of that set? †, §, and so on?

Comment: Thanks Xander, I am indeed describing an indexed family of functions. I've edited the question to make the domains of i and * more clear. I think a big part of my confusion is that * is a variable who's value is a reference to another variable {A, B, C, ...} (or its symbol), not the value of the other variable, if that makes sense. Unfortunately greek letters don't work well here because I am using them for parameters.

Comment: As I said in my answer above, you can use $\ast$ as an index from the set $\{A, B, C,\dotsc\}$, but such notation would be unusual and might cause confusion.  I think that you are better off using (for example) $\lambda$, $\mu$, $\nu$, etc as indices from the set $\Lambda = \{A, B, C, \dotsc\}$.